# Image Operations with Python

Tags: python, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I hope you're all doing well!

I'm new to Image Manipulation, and so I want to apologize right here for my simple question. I'm currently working on a problem that involves classifying an object called jet into two known categories. This object is made of sub-objects. My idea is to use this sub-objects to transform each jet in a pixel image, and then applying convolutional neural networks to find the patterns.

Here is an example of the pixel images:
[jet's constituents pixel distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kg119.png)

To standardize all the images, I want to find the two most intense pixels and make sure the axis connecting them is in the vertical direction, as well as make sure that the most intense pixel is at the top. It also would be good to impose that one of the sides (left or right) of the image contains the majority of the intensity and to normalize the intensity of the whole image to 1.

My question is: as I'm new to this kind of processing, I don't know if there is a library in Python that can handle these operations. Are you aware of any?

PS: the picture was taken from here:https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.5675

Answer (score 0):

You can look into OpenCV library for Python:
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html.
It supports a lot of image processing functions.

In your case, it probably would be easier to convert the image into a more suitable color space in which one axis stands for color intensity (e.g HSI, HSL, HSV) and trying to find indices of the maximum values along this axis (this should return the pixels with the highest intensity in the image).

Answer (score 0):

Generally, in Python, we use [PIL](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/tutorial.html) library for basic manipulations with images and [OpenCV](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) for advances ones.

But, if understand your task correctly, you can just think of an image as a multidimensional array and use [numpy](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/quickstart.html) to manipulate it.

For example, if your image is stored in a variable of type numpy.array called `img`, you can find maximum value along the desired axis just by writing:

```
img.max(axis=0)
```

To normalize image you can use:

```
img /= img.max()
```

To find which image part is brighter, you can split an `img` array into desired parts and calculate their mean:

```
left = img[:, :int(img.shape[1]/2), :]
right = img[:, int(img.shape[1]/2):, :]
left_mean = left.mean()
right_mean = right.mean()
```